# How to prove $(\Box (p\supset q)\land\Box( q\supset r))\supset\Box(p\supset r)$ in K

Tags: logic, modal-logic

$(\Box (p\supset q)\land\Box( q\supset r))\supset\Box(p\supset r)$

This is problem 2.1a in Hughes/Cresswell pg. 48.

So far I have this:

1. $(p \supset q)\supset((q\supset r)\supset(p\supset r)$, PC6
2. $[(p\supset q)\supset((q\supset r)\supset(p \supset r)]\supset[((p\supset q)\land(q\supset r))\supset(p\supset r)]$, PC7 [$(p\supset q)/p,(q\supset r)/q,(p\supset r)/r]$
3. $((p\supset q)\land(q\supset r))\supset(p\supset r)$, MP 1,2
4. $\Box[((p\supset q)\land(q\supset r))\supset(p\supset r)]$, N 3
5. $\Box((p\supset q)\land(q\supset r))\supset\Box(p\supset r)$, K 4

And here is where I'm stuck. I know that $\Box$ distributes over $\land$ in K. So I feel like a substitution instance of K3 needs to show up. Something like this:

$\Box((p\supset q)\land(q\supset r))\equiv(\Box(p\supset q)\land\Box(q\supset r))$

But I am not super comfortable with substitution of equivalents. If this were line 6, can I then infer a line 7 identical with 5, except 6 swaps for $\Box((p\supset q)\land(q\supset r))$?

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Is $\equiv$ a _connective_ in your logic, or a meta-level symbol? If it's a connective such that $\Box((p\supset q)\land(q\supset r))\equiv(\Box(p\supset q)\land\Box(q\supset r))$ is a _formula_, then you can apply the propositional tautology $(A\equiv B)\supset(A\supset B)$ to it, and then finish off with another instance of what it looks like you're calling "PC6".

Comment: @Troposphere $\equiv$ is a connective. Thanks so much! I really appreciate it! I was doing Semantic Tableaux (so much easier) but wanted to cut my teeth on the axiomatic stuff.

Comment: [This](https://www.umsu.de/trees/) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize, you know how to prove

$$\Box((p\supset q)\land(q\supset r))\supset\Box(p\supset r)$$
and
$$\Box((p\supset q)\land(q\supset r))\equiv(\Box(p\supset q)\land\Box(q\supset r))$$
and you want to eventually conclude
$$(\Box (p\supset q)\land\Box( q\supset r))\supset\Box(p\supset r)$$

---

Let's introduce some abbreviations, to combine some of the trees into forests:
$$A := \Box((p\supset q)\land(q\supset r)) \qquad B := \Box(p\supset r)
\qquad C:= \Box(p\supset q)\land\Box(q\supset r) $$
Then what you want is
$$ \text{from } A \supset B \text{ and } A \equiv C \text{ conclude } C \supset B $$
All of the *modal* boxes have disappeared into the abbreviations, so what is left is a purely propositional task. In fact,
$$ \tag{*} (A\equiv C) \supset((A\supset B)\supset (C\supset B)) $$
is a propositional tautology, so if you trust that your proof system can derive all of those, all you need now is two steps of MP.

Alternatively, it sounds like you might already have a "substitution of equivalents" meta-theorem that tells you that $(\text{*})$ can be derived.

If neither of those plans are available to you, I'd suggest doing it from scratch in two steps.
**First** prove $C\supset A$ from $A\equiv C$. This ought to be very simple; the fine details depend on which axioms for $\equiv$ you have to start from.
**Second**, it looks like $(C\supset A)\supset((A\supset B)\supset(C\supset B))$ is actually an instance of a logical axiom for you ("PC6"). You then have exactly the ingredients to get to $C\supset B$ in two MP steps.